Touchpad doesn't work on my Aspire E1-571-6824
I installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, 64-bit, on my Acer Aspire E1-571-6824 laptop. The touchpad wasn`t working since I started the installation process from a USB flash device using Pen Drive and continue to be not functional after successful installation. I updated the system but nothing got it worked.
